# Is there any way to convert docx to pdf in android using java?

Tags: java, android, pdf, type-conversion, docx

I try to use Apache POI in android but can't get success. Most of the resources in Apache POI use in java spring framework. Apache POI for android use only for xls sheets how I can convert DOCX/DOC to pdf.

https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/poi-android

Answer (score 0):

I got this:

```
private byte[] toPdf(ByteArrayOutputStream docx) {
    InputStream isFromFirstData = new ByteArrayInputStream(docx.toByteArray());

    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(isFromFirstData);
    PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();

    //make new file in c:\temp\
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\tmp\\HelloWord.pdf"));
    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);

    //return byte array for return in http request.
    ByteArrayOutputStream pdf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, pdf, options);

    document.write(pdf);
    document.close();
    return pdf.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Its only work on JVM machine not on android which is used dalvik virtual machine.